# Cypress.io - Using location.href to redirect user to same origin results in Cross Origin Error

Tags: cypress

I'm seeing this error when doing a `location.href` to redirect my user to a different `path` on the same `host`. To illustrate, I'm redirecting from `https://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/newpage`.

I know that `Cypress` strips out any `subdomains` (in this case, `www`) and sets the `host` as `document.domain`, so I don't understand why this isn't working.

> Error:     CypressError: Cypress detected a cross origin error
> happened  on page load:
>
> ```
> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from  accessing 
> a cross-origin frame.
>
> Before the page load, you were bound to the origin policy:
>   https://example.com
> ```

[According to the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Same-origin), both `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` are considered `same-origin`, so why the error?

I'm on `Cypress 6.1.0.`